# Prove a factor is III$_{\lambda}$ type

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

This question is from the Sunder's book *An Invitation to von Neumann Algebras* Ex 4.2.13

> Let M be a semifinite factor with fns trace ${\tau}$. Let ${\theta}$
>   be an automorphism of M such that ${\tau}$ ${\theta}$ = ${\lambda}$
>   ${\tau}$ for some  ${\lambda}$ in (0,1). Define ab action  ${\alpha}$
>   of Z on M by  ${\alpha}$$_n$ =  ${\theta}$$^n$, prove that the crossed
>   product $\widetilde M%$ is of type  III$_{\lambda}$.

There is a hint to used the following prop 4.2.9, but I also cannot catch the ideal of prop 4.2.9, it seems that the condition (ii) is complicated, please help.

[image]